# Strtok-ing a file into an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, strtok

Somehow I can't get this to display correctly, no matter how i rearrange things. I should be able to accomplish this without using malloc, by the way.

```
void ArrayFormatter(FILE* cipherKey)
{
    char line[1000];
    char* fileWords[5000]; 
    static int wordCount = 0; 

    //This loop stores each word into its corresponding position in an array
    while(fgets(line, 1000, cipherKey) != NULL) 
    { 
            fileWords[wordCount] = strtok(line, " "); 
            fprintf(stdout, "_%s_", fileWords[wordCount]); //test 
            wordCount++;                                                    
            for(i = 0; i < sizeof(line) - 1; i++) 
            {                                                               
                    fileWords[wordCount] = strtok(NULL, " ");                

                    if(fileWords[wordCount] == NULL)                        
                            break; 

                    fprintf(stdout, "_%s_", fileWords[wordCount]); //test     
                    wordCount++; 
            }                                                                 
    }                                                                         
    fprintf(stdout, "\n\n\n");                                                

    //Issue here is that it's not displaying the same values that it is     above
    //This loop displays current strings, in order,  in array 
    for(i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) 
    { 
            fprintf(stdout, "_%s_", fileWords[i]); 
    }
```

Comment: Are you certain there are spaces in `line`?

Comment: @user3121023 What would I have to do to remedy that? I can't find any resource online that's been helpful to me.

Comment: Is there not a way to accomplish this without dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: *I should be able to accomplish this without using malloc, by the way.*  Well, you might.  But you sure can't do it by storing just the pointer returned from `strtok()`, since that will point to a string in your `char line[1000]; array`.  And whatever each pointer you store will point to memory that gets overwritten with the next call to `fgets()`...

Comment: I see. I'll try to work off that.

Comment: Is it a hard requirement that you cannot use `calloc/malloc`?

Comment: after adding the missing statements: `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <string.h>`  it became clear that the variable `i` is not defined within the posted code.  Perhaps you want to change from: `for(i = 0; i < sizeof(line) - 1; i++)` to `for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(line) - 1; i++)`  AND from: `for(i = 0; i < wordCount; i++)` to `for(size_t i = 0; i < wordCount; i++)`

Comment: the posted code is not compilable, because the posted function is missing the code after the `for()` loop

Comment: the variable `wordCount` will never be negative, so suggest changing the declaration from: `static int wordCount = 0;` to `static size_t wordCount = 0;`

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using a `enum` or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names then use those meaningful names throughout the code.  'magic' numbers like 1000 and 5000.

Comment: The declaration of `fileWords[]`  is not adequate for the job.  Suggest: 1) move the declaration of `fileWords` from the stack to file global space.  2) add a second `[...]` to define a max word length.   3) remove the `*` from the declaration, similar to: `char fileWords[5000][50] = {{'\0'}};   Then modify the lines that call `strtok()` to assign some local char pointer, followed by a call to strncpy()` to place the word into the `fileWords[][]` array

Answer (score 0):

*I should be able to accomplish this without using malloc, by the way.*

You can do it without `malloc`, but you will need a large stack, and to change the following line:

```
 char* fileWords[5000];
```

To:

```
 char fileWords[5000][anticipated largest string length+1];
```

And, create a `char *buf={0};` (or similar) to use with `strtok`

As mentioned in the comments, there are other problems in your code.

If you should decide to use malloc...

<strike>Three</strike> Four suggestions to make initial debugging easier:
0) Allocate memory for each `char* fileWords[5000];` before using, free after.
1) make sure the delimiter contains the right values.
2) check the return coming out of `strtok`.
3) move the print loop out of the read/parse loop.

```
char *buf={0};
int wordCount = 0;

while(fgets(line, 1000, cipherKey) != NULL) 
{ 
        buf = strtok(line, " ");//are you certain this is the right delimiter list?
        while(buf)//check the return of strtok before using 
        {
            fileWords[wordCount] = malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
            strcpy(fileWords[wordCount], buf);//store intermediate results
            wordCount++;                                                    
            buf = strtok(line, NULL);//get new token from string
        }
}
for(i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) 
{                                                               
    fprintf(stdout, "_%s_", fileWords[i]); //test
    free(fileWords[i]);     
}
```

Comment: Also, instead of `if(buf)`, you probably should use `while(buf)` so the code will process more than the first two tokens in the line.

Comment: @user3121023 It's also possible to define `fileWords` as 2-dimensional array and copy words (of a max length) into it:  `char fileWords[5000][MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1];`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the corrected code. It has a few more safety checks for array overflow and blank lines. On the odd chance that *no* `malloc` was a requirement, I've added a "non malloc" version of `strdup(3)` [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#define LINESIZE    1000
#define WORDMAX     5000
#define BUFMAX      ((WORDMAX + 1) * LINESIZE)

char strarea[BUFMAX];
char *strptr;

// xstrdup -- "no malloc" version of strdup(3)
char *
xstrdup(const char *src)
{
    int len = strlen(src) + 1;
    char *dst;

    if (strptr == NULL)
        strptr = strarea;

    dst = strptr;
    strptr += len;

    memcpy(dst,src,len);

    return dst;
}

void
ArrayFormatter(FILE *cipherKey)
{
    char line[LINESIZE];
    char *bp;
    char *cp;
    char *fileWords[WORDMAX];
    int wordCount = 0;

    // This loop stores each word into its corresponding position in an array
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), cipherKey) != NULL) {
        bp = line;

        for (;  wordCount < WORDMAX;  ++wordCount) {
            cp = strtok(bp, " ");
            bp = NULL;

            if (cp == NULL)
                break;

            // standard way or if no malloc is hard requirement, use xstrdup
#if 1
            fileWords[wordCount] = strdup(cp);
#else
            fileWords[wordCount] = xstrdup(cp);
#endif

            fprintf(stdout, "_%s_", fileWords[wordCount]);  // test
        }

        if (wordCount >= WORDMAX)
            break;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "\n\n\n");

    // Issue here is that it's not displaying the same values that it is above
    // This loop displays current strings, in order, in array
    for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
        fprintf(stdout, "_%s_", fileWords[i]);
    }

#if 0
    for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
        free(fileWords[i]);
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize strptr to NULL for your code to work.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt No, strptr is global, so it will be in `BSS` and will have a zero value

Answer (score 0):

the following code

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functions
3. does not use `malloc()` nor `calloc()` nor `realloc()`
4. is limited to words with a max length of 49 characters
5. is limited to 5000 words

and now the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN (1000)
#define MAX_WORDS    (5000)
#define MAX_WORD_LEN (50)


void ArrayFormatter(FILE* cipherKey)
{
    char line[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    size_t wordCount = 0;

    static char fileWords[ MAX_WORDS ][ MAX_WORD_LEN ];

    //This loop stores each word into its corresponding position in an array
    while(wordCount < MAX_WORDS && fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN, cipherKey) )
    {
        char * token = strtok(line, " ");

        while( token )
        {
            strncpy( fileWords[wordCount], token,  MAX_WORD_LEN);
            fprintf(stdout, "_%s_", fileWords[wordCount]); // test
            wordCount++;

            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "\n\n\n");

    //This loop displays current strings, in order,  in array
    for(size_t i = 0; i < wordCount; i++)
    {
            fprintf(stdout, "_%s_", fileWords[i]);
    }
} // end function: ArrayFormatter
```